# Where is torch.cholesky and how torch refers to its methods?

Tags: pytorch

I'm doing some research into Cholesky decomposition, which requires some insights into how `torch.cholesky` works. After a while of grep-ing and searching through ATen, I got stuck at TensorMethods.h, which interestingly has this following code:

```
inline Tensor Tensor::cholesky(bool upper) const {
#ifdef USE_STATIC_DISPATCH
    return TypeDefault::cholesky(const_cast<Tensor&>(*this), upper);
#else
    static c10::OperatorHandle op = c10::Dispatcher::singleton().findSchema({"aten::cholesky", ""}).value();
    return c10::Dispatcher::singleton().callUnboxed<Tensor, const Tensor &, bool>(
        op, impl::dispatchTypeId(at::detail::multi_dispatch_tensor_type_set(*this)), const_cast<Tensor&>(*this), upper);
#endif
}
```

This raised the question of how torch locates its methods. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [aten/src/ATen/native/README.md](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/README.md) which describes how functions are registered to the API.

> ATen "native" functions are the modern mechanism for adding operators
>   and functions to ATen (they are "native" in contrast to legacy
>   functions, which are bound via TH/THC cwrap metadata). Native
>   functions are declared in native_functions.yaml and have
>   implementations defined in one of the cpp files in this directory.

If we take a look at [aten/src/ATen/native/native_functions.yaml](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/native_functions.yaml) and search for `cholesky` we find

```
- func: cholesky(Tensor self, bool upper=False) -> Tensor
  use_c10_dispatcher: full
  variants: method, function
```

To find the entry-point you basically just have to search the .cpp files in the [aten/src/ATen/native](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/master/aten/src/ATen/native) directory and locate the function named `cholesky`. Currently it can be found at [BatchLinearAlgebra.cpp:550](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/c780610f2d8358297cb4e4460692d496e124d64d/aten/src/ATen/native/BatchLinearAlgebra.cpp#L550)

```
Tensor cholesky(const Tensor &self, bool upper) {
  if (self.size(-1) == 0) {
    return at::empty_like(self, LEGACY_CONTIGUOUS_MEMORY_FORMAT);
  }
  squareCheckInputs(self);

  auto raw_cholesky_output = at::_cholesky_helper(self, upper);
  if (upper) {
    return raw_cholesky_output.triu_();
  } else {
    return raw_cholesky_output.tril_();
  }
}
```

From this point it's just a matter of following the C++ code to understand what's going on.

Comment: Forgive my lack of knowledge in this, but I realized that I was assuming the python version of torch library had all the C++ code available. They are stored in shared objects, `.so` files, which is why I couldn't find the function `cholesky`. Thank you so much for the great reply !!