# Where is the definition of torch.embedding in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to understand how PyTorch creates embeddings and read the source code of `torch.nn.functional.embedding` [github link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b85568a54a9c60986235ad1e0cc5dffc71b9d5b1/torch/nn/functional.py#L1844).
The function returns the result of `torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)`.
Then, I try to understand the definition of `torch.embedding` but I can't find its source code in the GitHub repository. Where is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many of PyTorch's functions are implemented in C++. The entrypoint for `torch.embedding` is located [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b85568a54a9c60986235ad1e0cc5dffc71b9d5b1/aten/src/ATen/native/Embedding.cpp#L14).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, jodag!
Could you please tell me how do you tell the code is located there?

Comment: @HayatoMaki Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59993245/2790047) which describes how to find function implementations in pytorch.